# How to determine cause for sporadic macbook freezes?

Tags: macos, freeze, macos-mojave

For a few weeks now, my macbook pro freezes for 10-20 seconds completely, except the mouse. I can freely move the mouse around, but everything else remains locked. Volume buttons do nothing, music continues playing, but visually everything except the mouse is locked.

I've tried checking the system logs in the console.app, but there's too much noise around the time it happens - I'm completely unsure how to filter down to what may give a better idea on what's happening.

I do wonder if this may be the GPU ageing, as often any UIs that are open seem to refresh after the freeze. Slack, chrome, outlook, or any other app that's got an open window seems to clear and reload the window visually.

Does anyone know how I can investigate deeper? I'm comfortable with terminal.

EDIT: Looks like sometimes when this happens, some background helps crash. It's not always the same helper, but I've seen this happen with anything that seems to use the electron framework. Example, skype:

```
Process:               Skype Helper [1818]
Path:                  /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Frameworks/Skype Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype Helper
Identifier:            Skype Helper
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Skype [1814]
Responsible:           Skype [1814]
User ID:               778701435

Date/Time:             2019-06-04 12:10:59.346 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F132)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        8AD07C6C-3EFE-5D39-B58B-393D95473947

Sleep/Wake UUID:       2040C466-8BB3-4DE0-B29B-36AEA64EB560

Time Awake Since Boot: 240000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       9700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1  Watchdog

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000104cd3000-0000000104cd4000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Frameworks/Skype Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype Helper

Thread 0:: CrGpuMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7305222a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7305276c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff498f4f13 io_connect_method + 374
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff498f4d75 IOConnectCallMethod + 244
4   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff498f55ab IOConnectCallStructMethod + 38
5   com.apple.IOAccelerator         0x00007fff64361cb9 IOAccelContextSubmitDataBuffersExt2 + 258
6   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00007fff620845ce gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 136
7   com.apple.AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver    0x000000010ef6843a glrATI_Hwl_SubmitPacketsWithToken + 110
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001073b2d0b 0x104ce1000 + 40705291
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106b59a9d 0x104ce1000 + 31951517
10  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106b59fc8 0x104ce1000 + 31952840
11  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106b5a6d2 0x104ce1000 + 31954642
12  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106a8cb7b 0x104ce1000 + 31112059
13  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106a9ee13 0x104ce1000 + 31186451
14  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106ae13a8 0x104ce1000 + 31458216
15  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106b60677 0x104ce1000 + 31979127
16  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106b604ac 0x104ce1000 + 31978668
17  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106b5f1f3 0x104ce1000 + 31973875
18  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106b66a57 0x104ce1000 + 32004695
19  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106b64fd2 0x104ce1000 + 31997906
20  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106adefbb 0x104ce1000 + 31449019
21  com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010806f301 0x104ce1000 + 54059777
22  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001080c6c2c 0x104ce1000 + 54418476
23  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001080c7398 0x104ce1000 + 54420376
24  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001080d764a 0x104ce1000 + 54486602
25  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000108050f2a 0x104ce1000 + 53935914
26  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001080d6f6f 0x104ce1000 + 54484847
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4700c083 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff4700c029 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 108
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff46fef9eb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 195
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff46feefb5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1189
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff46fee8be CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 455
32  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff492528ef -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 280
33  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001080d7b5e 0x104ce1000 + 54487902
34  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001080d6a8e 0x104ce1000 + 54483598
35  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000108031cc5 0x104ce1000 + 53808325
36  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001062d2604 0x104ce1000 + 23008772
37  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001062d5509 0x104ce1000 + 23020809
38  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000108ab68b2 0x104ce1000 + 64837810
39  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001062d4a54 0x104ce1000 + 23018068
40  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000104ce2f84 AtomMain + 68
41  com.skype.skype.Helper          0x0000000104cd3f89 main + 9
42  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff72f1d3d5 start + 1

Thread 1 Crashed:: Watchdog
0   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000106b5bb19 0x104ce1000 + 31959833
1   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010806f301 0x104ce1000 + 54059777
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001080c6c2c 0x104ce1000 + 54418476
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001080c74d6 0x104ce1000 + 54420694
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001080c78dc 0x104ce1000 + 54421724
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000108031cc5 0x104ce1000 + 53808325
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000108063153 0x104ce1000 + 54010195
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010806645d 0x104ce1000 + 54023261
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff731112eb _pthread_body + 126
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff73114249 _pthread_start + 66
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7311040d thread_start + 13
```

This is always the same kind of crash log after this happened, including this in the details:

```
Thread 0:: CrGpuMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Comment: Are you running Time Machine? Parallels? What about updates coming in?

Comment: One other to check is Anti-virus. I use Sophos and notice app freezes when it appears Sophos is updating.

Comment: Depending on how old your Macbook is, another frequent reason for unexplainable crashes and hangs is RAM gone bad.

Comment: No antivirus installed and time machine isn't running. Updates are manually installed, I'm currently on the latest mojave release (10.14.5). How would I go about identifying if it's the RAM going bad?

Do the keywords CrGpuMain or Watchdog give any hints? If a helper crashes after this, it's always with this same cause.

Comment: You can reset the RAM and see if that helps:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063  The only way to know if the hardware is bad is to reset the OS.  Apples aren't exactly designed to let you swap parts out most of the time.  Resetting the OS would remove any unwanted software, and if the problem persists, then it is probably the hardware going bad.  Make sure to backup everything if you are going to reset the OS just in-case.

Comment: Might be a bug on electron. Could you give this a look? https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13751

Comment: Thanks @JourneymanGeek, though it seems that would show in the crash log. If I see a crashlog after this event, it's always with CrGpuMain and Watchdog as primary keywords